# Deauthorizing ArcGIS for Desktop 60 Day Trial

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-license-manager

I installed ArcGIS For Desktop Advanced 60 Day Trial. I'm not sure what went wrong, but I didn't get a clean install. I uninstalled it.

I later installed ArcGIS For Desktop, and went through the authorization wizard to configure it as a Single User license under my company's organization.

Everything looked like it worked fine, except that when I try to run ArcMap, it loads the splash screen, sits for 30 seconds, then disappears.

When I run ArcGIS Administrator, I see Desktop. I can run through the Authorization Wizard, and it tells me everything is authorized. But when I look at the availability list, everything is set to expire in June, 60 days after I installed the free trial, not in November when the company's license expires.

If I go in to Deauthorize, I see two items:

- ArcGIS for Desktop Advanced 60 Day Trial - expires 27-Jun-2016
- EDN ArcGIS for Desktop Basic - expires 01-Dec-2016

If I try to deauthorize the free trial, I get an error message: "7466: The return of the fulfillment is denied by the return policy because max return exceeded [Incident# 8414-03497135]"

I've uninstalled all the ArcGIS products, walked through and removed all the ArcGIS registry settings, reinstalled the EDN Desktop Basic, and I still see the free trial showing up in the ArcGIS Adminstrator lists.

Am I right in supposing that it's the presence of this aborted free trial install that's keeping my fresh install from working?

And how can I get rid of it?

Comment: The fastest way to resolve this is probably going to be to contact ESRI customer support. You may not be able to fix this if the problem is with your license status on ESRI's activation servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trial licenses can not be deauthorized. Deauthorize your Basic license from your organisation. Go to "C:\ProgramData\FLEXnet" and delete the documents inside the Flexnet folder. This will clear the information recorded by your arcgis administrator. Authorize the basic license from your organisation and you're ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

License queries need to go through to whoever issued your license. This would normally be Esri or one of their distributors.

Contact details for Esri and their distributors can be found on the [Esri Contact Us](http://www.esri.com/about-esri/contact) page.

Comment: I've already filed a support ticket, and haven't heard back, yet.